# composition rule in category theory

Tags: category-theory

I just started with learning category theory and one of rule to be qualified as category is **Composition** according to which if there is morphism/arrow :

A->B and B->C and there should be arrow from object A to C i.e A->C must exist.

**I have a very basic question**: Is there any situation where above rule cannot be met in first place ? Probably some example would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean an example of a category where composition is not always defined? Or just some algebraic structural thingy where you need not have that morphisms $A\to B,B\to C \implies A\to C$ exists?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer : Actually I don't know. I kind of learning functional programming and one thing I came to know is that FP concepts are from category theory, so I started also going through this topic. When I saw definition of  category - **composition** was one of the rule mentioned. In context of programming, I see this as if f:A->B and g:B->C then there should be h:A->C (h = gof) So I was wondering how this can be rule. I mean this is obvious and where this rule can even fail. Hence question. thx!!

Comment: How about this: consider the set of integers $\Bbb Z$ and define just one arrow between $a$ and $b$ if $a$ and $b$ have opposite parity (and no arrow if they have the same parity)?

Comment: I think I just over complicated it. If A & B are friend and B & C are friend then A & C need not be friend and hence A,B and C does not form category..isn't it ? but had relation been brother among objects  A, B and C then they would have formed category. It's all my thinking..might be wrong too.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal While there are some categorical concepts that have been incorporated into the practice of functional programming, FP concepts don't usually come from category theory though there are deep connections. Arguably, FP is older than category theory if you pick the creation of the lambda calculus as the start of functional programming. (Even picking the creation of LISP as the start would make it about the same age.) Either way, composition of functions is certainly far older than category theory or functional programming. Category theory *abstracts* from this concrete example.